# How can I add multiple elements with HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a mobile app which sets reminders for the users depending on what they enter in the input page, pretty simple stuff. The reminders themselves show as cards in the home page that the user should be able to edit or delete any time. The dilemma here is: I don't really know how to do that...

So here's an example of what I'm trying to get at:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("remindCard").innerHTML = document.getElementById("remindMe").value;
  document.getElementById("delBtn").style.display = "block";
}

function delReminder() {
  document.getElementById("remindCard").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("delBtn").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input id="remindMe" placeholder="Add Reminder:">
  <button id="btnSubmit" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>


  <!--
    Cards which contain the reminder itself and a button to delete:
    -->
  <h1 id="remindCard"></h1>
  <button id="delBtn" onclick="delReminder()" style="display:none;">Delete Reminder</button>

</body>

</html>
```

To recap: I want to have multiple of these cards without making multiple headings and JavaScript functions, how do I do this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are allowing user to add multiple alarms with edit or delete functionality ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Please response to answers \.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I responded to the answer and also marked it as the official answer for this thread :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Javascript you can build your cards in real time:

```js
function createCard() {
  // Takes the value of the input field
  //
  let text = document.getElementById('text').value;

  // Builds the card with the wanted text
  //
  let card = document.createElement('div');
  card.innerHTML = `<h1>${text}</h1>
    <button class="delete-btn">Delete Reminder</button>`

  // Attach a click event handler to remove the card
  //
  let delete_btn = card.querySelector('.delete-btn');
  delete_btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.body.removeChild(card);
  });

  // Appends the card to the document's body
  //
  document.body.appendChild(card);
}
```

```html
<input id="text" placeholder="Reminder:">
<button onclick="createCard()">Add</button>
```

Comment: Looks like this works for me! Sorry for the late response, I was busy implementing this logic into the code.

Comment: Quick question, I have just tried this code in another project of mine; what if I have multiple pages, and I want the input to be on one page, and the cards to show up in another?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function called to create separate reminder. In that function create a container div. Inside container `<div>` create three element

- Heading to display
- A button to delete the reminder
- A button which update the text of reminder to value of the main input

```js
const reminders = document.getElementById('reminders');
const remindMe = document.getElementById("remindMe");
function createReminder(){
  //Create a new wrapper div and give it a class "reminder"
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = "reminder";
  
  //Create the element for text dispay
  const textElement = document.createElement('h3');
  
  //Change its innerHTML to the value of input
  textElement.innerHTML = remindMe.value;
 
  //Create a delete button.
  const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
  deleteButton.innerHTML = "delete";
  //Whenever this specific delete button is clicked. Delete the corresponding wrapper div.
  deleteButton.onclick = function(){
    div.remove()
  };
  
  //Create an update button
  const updateButton = document.createElement('button');
  updateButton.innerHTML = "update"
  
  //Whenever this button is clicked change the text of corresponding textElement
  updateButton.onclick = function(){
    textElement.innerHTML = remindMe.value
  }
  
  //Add all there element to the wrapper div
  div.appendChild(textElement);
  div.appendChild(deleteButton);
  div.appendChild(updateButton);
  
  //At last add the wrapper div to main list of reminders
  reminders.appendChild(div)
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input id="remindMe" placeholder="Add Reminder:">
  <button id="btnSubmit" onclick="createReminder()">Submit</button>


  <!--
    Cards which contain the reminder itself and a button to delete:
    -->
  <div id="reminders"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an infinite amount of cards, you need to create a function which builds them for you. So that when you push the `submit` button your function will construct everything necessary to build a single card and adds it where you want it.

With [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) you can create new elements in JavaScript and manipulate them to your liking. When you've created your elements you can [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) them to each other to build nested HTML elements.

When dynamically adding elements it's generally a good practice to utilize *event delegation*, meaning having a single event handler which handles all situations based on the element it has been clicked on. So for example, when clicking a button, check if it is the remove button and if so, remove the element from your list. This is good for memory consumption and does not require you to listen for an event on every single element.

Listen to your events from within your JavaScript file with [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Every element is also an `EventTarget` and has this method to listen for events. Using this, instead of inline `on[event]` attributes, keeps your HTML clean and void of JavaScript, and also enables you to add as many functions to a single event as you want. [This article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) explains it in more details.

```js
// Select the form and the list for the cards.
const createCardForm = document.getElementById('create-card');
const cardList = document.getElementById('card-list');

/**
 * Function for building a single card.
 * Returns the card element.
 */
function createCard(text) {

  // Create wrapper, heading and button.
  const wrapper = document.createElement('li');
  const heading = document.createElement('h3');
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  
  // Set the classes and the texts of these elements.
  wrapper.classList.add('card');
  heading.textContent = text;
  button.textContent = 'Delete reminder';
  button.classList.add('js-remove-card');
  
  // Add the heading and button the wrapper;
  wrapper.append(heading, button);
  
  // Return the wrapper from the function.
  return wrapper;
}

/**
 * Function for removing a single card.
 */
function removeCard(button) {
  const card = button.closest('.card');
  card.remove();
}

/**
 * Listen for submit on form element to get the value
 * from the form and pass it to the createCard function.
 */
createCardForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  const title = formData.get('card-title');
  const card = createCard(title);
  cardList.append(card);
  event.preventDefault();
});

/**
 * Listen to ALL clicks on the page and do something
 * when a condition is met. This enables all generated
 * buttons to be captured by this event handler.
 */
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const removeButton = event.target.closest('.js-remove-card');
  if (removeButton !== null) {
    removeCard(removeButton);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
#card-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.card {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form id="create-card">
  <input name="card-title" type="text" placeholder="Add Reminder:">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<ul id="card-list">

</ul>
```